# Excel Macro - copy cells from one sheet into another based on value

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I would like to copy cells from one Sheet into another based on Values in one Column. The problem is I want to copy the values and not the formulas, but I can't get the Destination command to work with Pastespecial. So far I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, _
Cancel As Boolean)

Dim i, LastRow

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Available").Cells.ClearContents

For Each c In Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

If UCase(c.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "Not Sold" Then

Range("A" & c.Row & ":" & "G" & c.Row).Copy _

Destination:=Sheets("Available").Range("A" & Rows.Count) _

.End(xlUp).Offset(1)

End If

Next c

Target.Offset(1).Select
End Sub
```

I also want to copy some cells above the cell with the value and add it to the right side of the row copied to the new sheet.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The problem lies here `UCase(c.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "Not Sold"`. UCase implies that the word would be in **all upper case**. Change `"Not Sold"` to `"NOT SOLD"` or remove the `UCase` wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me point out a couple things I don't think are working, or a good idea.

Using `If UCase(c.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "Not Sold"` should fail every time, since you're converting to uppercase and then comparing it.  You want `If Ucase(c.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "NOT SOLD"`

Second, you're setting up `i` and `LastRow` as `Variants`, instead of `Integers`, which I believe is what you want.  Technically not a problem but I don't like unknown variables.  You also don't seem to be using `i`, unless I'm overlooking something.

Finally, to find the last row accurately, I would use

```
lastRow = Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).row
```

This is the most reliable method of finding the last row that I know of, and actually [found right here on stack.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)

Now, for the actual code itself, here is my recommendation.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, _ Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim i, LastRow as Integer
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Available")

    i = 1

    LastRow = ws1.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    ws2.Cells.ClearContents

    For Each c In Range(Cells(1,2), Cells(LastRow, 2))
        If UCase(c.Value) = "NOT SOLD" Then
            ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(i, 1), ws2.Cells(i, 7)).Value = ws1.Range( _
                ws1.Cells(c.Row, 1), ws1.Cells(c.Row, 7)).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next c

    Target.Offset(1).Select 

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't like the following 2 rows: ws2.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 7)).Value = Range( _
                Cells(c.Row, 1), Cells(c.Row, 7)).Value

Comment: Contract them into one line.  `ws2.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 7)).Value = Range(Cells(c.Row, 1), Cells(c.Row, 7)).Value`  I might be getting my formatting wrong for multiple lines.

Comment: Still not happy... I'll see if I can get the formatting sorted.

Comment: This is still not working for me. Can someone help please.

Comment: @ImadAli Sorry, I realized that `i` is declared, but never set to a value, so when it's trying to copy the values it doesn't have a valid cell.  I've corrected the code.